# How to autoconfigure datasource using java-cfenv-boot

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, java-cfenv

From what I gather (See [here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/configuring-service-connections.html)), adding java-cfenv-boot as maven dependency should autoconfigure the available datasource for cloud foundry deployment. However, at the time of deployment, its not able to find the required parameters.

The application is able to access the vcap.services data as a string which can be parsed using CfJdbcEnv. But if I try to access the data in properties file, I can only access `vcap.services` directly, but not the individual service data, i.e. `vcap.services.<service-label>` data is not available.

Do I need to add anything else to pom or properties to autoconfigure datasource using the environment data?

Answer (score 1):

> not the individual service data, i.e. vcap.services. data is not available.

In a properties or YAML Spring Boot config file, the `vcap.services.<foo>` properties are set by Spring Boot itself, not the java-cfenv library.

See [CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/cloud/CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor.java).

If they are not set, then my first thought would be that the post processor isn't running. That seems odd and you might want to look into what's happening in your app, however, it's not strictly necessary.

You can fetch the properties using java-cfenv. To do that, you need to create a `CfEnv` bean, then you can use SPeL to use the bean to access properties in your config file.

1. Create the bean:

   ```
   @Bean
   public CfEnv cfEnv() {
     return new CfEnv();
   }
   ```

   Alternatively, for JDBC you can create a `CfJdbcEnv` which is a little more convenient.

   ```
   @Bean
   public CfJdbcEnv cfJdbcEnv() {
     return new CfJdbcEnv();
   }
   ```
2. Use a SPeL expression to invoke the bean.

   Example using `CfJdbcEnv`

   ```
   spring.datasource.url=#{ cfJdbcEnv.findJdbcService().getUrl() }
   ```

   and an example using `CfEnv`.

   ```
   spring.datasource.username=#{ cfEnv.findCredentialsByTag('my-db').get('username') }
   ```

Reference docs: https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv/#use-with-spring

> Do I need to add anything else to pom or properties to autoconfigure datasource using the environment data?

For common properties, what I mentioned above isn't even necessary. The `spring.datasource.url` property, for example, should be automatically set.

The `CfDataSourceEnvironmentPostProcessor` sets the Spring Boot property `spring.datasource.url`. This is also a post processor though, and since you seem to be having trouble with post processors, `CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor` does not seem to be working either, that is probably the cause of your issues.

Reference doc: https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv/#using-spring-boot

Comment: Thanks for all the details.. I have, in fact, implemented the workaround you suggested. But, I would like to understand why the post processor is not working. CfDataSourceEnvironmentPostProcessor is being triggered on local system (debugger reaches the relevant code). But logs on server give me an error on the lines of "unsupported/unrecognised jdbc url" and vcap.services.<foo> is not initialized

Comment: It sounds like there's some value or entry in the `VCAP_SERVICES` env variable that's not being recognized. I would suggest you capture the full contents of `VCAP_SERVICES` by running `cf env` and try running with that locally. See if you can trigger the problem. If you can, then sanitize the information in `VCAP_SERVICES` and re-run to confirm you can still reproduce the issue. Assuming that you can reproduce, open an issue https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv/issues. If you can't reproduce after sanitizing then you changed something in the data that is triggering the issue.